# Using while to exit for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that prints first ten elements of the list and then prints end:

```
a = ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","110"]
n = 0
limit= 10
while n != limit:
    for b in a:
        if "1" in b:
            print(b)
            n += 1
print("end")
```

I am trying to figure out why it breaks if I add more numbers to the list.

```
a = ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","110","111","112"]
n = 0
limit= 10
while n != limit:
    for b in a:
        if "1" in b:
            print(b)
            n += 1
print("end")
```

Goes on forever, printing the numbers again and again. Can someone explain why?

I have already replaced it with this but I just want to understand what was wrong with the first one.

```
a = ["11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","110","111","112"]
n = 0
limit= 10
for b in a:
    if "1" in b:
        print(b)
        n += 1
    if n == limit:
        break
print("end")
```

What was wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this code that prints first ten elements of the list and then prints end

That's not what your original code does.  The `for` loop will iterate over all elements of the list, no matter how long.  So, the `while` condition is only checked after you've iterated over the entire list.

So, when the code starts, the first `while` check is before any looping, and checks `0 != 10`.  It's then not checked again until the `for` loop has visited every element of the list.  Because your first list has exactly 10 elements with "1" in them, it turns out `n` will be exactly 10, and the second time the `while` condition is tested, it will be `10 == 10`.  But in your second example, where you have 11 elements, the `while` condition won't be checked until `n` is 11.

Try putting print statements in various spots to see what's going on, e.g. just after the `while` statement, just after the `for` statement, just after the `if` statement.  That will show you which statements are executed when.

Answer (score 1):

You add **more than 1** at each *turn in the (`while`) loop*, so before the loop, `n` is **smaller** thant `10`, and after, it is **greater** than `n`. Thus, never **equals** `10`.

Just change the condition to `>=` (or `>` depending on what you want).

Comment: Thanks! I thought while would check for the condition every time one of the variables changed, but apparently it checks once a loop.

Comment: A `while` loop is pretty much the same as a `for` loop, the condition is checked only when you go **through** the condition line (so each time the loop start/restart). There is no reason to check in the middle of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am not still convinced that whatever you are doing is right. If fr sure you want to print the first 10 elements in the list, use this approach:

```
a = ["1", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "110", "111", "112"]

limit = 10
for i in a[0:limit]:
    print(i)
print("end")
```

Comment: This is even better. Thanks!

Comment: Changed my mind, doesn't work if the list has elements that don't contain 1

Comment: You wanted to print first 10 elements where element contains 1. Right?

Comment: Yes. Couldn't think of a way to do that with this approach. Edit: For clarity, I wanted to print first 10 elements that contain 1.